# My square root function isn't working

Tags: jquery, calculator

I am building a calculator with HTML and jQuery.

Take a look at my square root function. When I press the sqrt button, it returns NaN. Why? I have just tried putting `parseFloat(number)` and it also returns NaN. Please help me!

```
Jquery:


$(document).ready(function(){
    var testNumLength = function(number) {
        if (number.length > 9) {
            totaldiv.text(number.substr(number.length-9,9));
            if (number.length > 15) {
                number = "";
                totaldiv.text("Err");
            }
        } 
    };
    var number = "";
    var newnumber = "";
    var operator = "";
    var totaldiv = $("#total");
    totaldiv.text("0");
    $("#numbers a").not("#clear,#clearall").click(function(){
        number += $(this).text();
        totaldiv.text(number);
        testNumLength(number);
    });
    $("#operators a, #side a").not("#equals, #decimal").click(function(){
        operator = $(this).text();
        newnumber = number;
        number = "";
        totaldiv.text("0");
        if($(this).attr('id') === "sqrt") {
            operator = "sqrt";
            $("#equals").click();
        }
    });
    $("#clear,#clearall").click(function(){
        number = "";
        totaldiv.text("0");
        if ($(this).attr("id") === "clearall") {
            newnumber = "";
        }
    });
    //Add your last .click() here!
    $("#equals").click(function(){
        if (operator === "+"){
            number = (parseInt(number, 10) + parseInt(newnumber,10)).toString(10);
        } else if (operator === "-"){
            number = (parseInt(newnumber, 10) - parseInt(number,10)).toString(10);
        } else if (operator === "÷"){
            number = (parseInt(newnumber, 10) / parseInt(number,10)).toString(10);
        } else if (operator === "×"){
            number = (parseInt(newnumber, 10) * parseInt(number,10)).toString(10);
        } else if (operator === "sqrt") {
            number = Math.sqrt(parseFloat(number,10)).toString(10);
        }
        totaldiv.text(number);
        testNumLength(number);
        number = "";
        newnumber = "";
    });
    $('#decimal').click(function(){
        var numOfDecs = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
            if(number[i] === ".") {
                totaldiv.text(number[i]);
            }
        }
        if (numOfDecs === 0) {
            number.append('.');
            totaldiv.text(number);
            testNumLengh(number);
        }
    })
});
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fqdxkL4y/

Comment: Please add your html, or even better, create a working snippet with the example of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `alert` here, you'll see that `number` is not passed here or passed as having no value.

```
else if (operator === "sqrt") {
    // alert(number);
    number = Math.sqrt(parseFloat(number,10)).toString(10);
}
```

As suggested by SK Jajoriya. But be aware, you have to workaround the constraint having long number.

Comment: How can I make it pass through?

Answer (score 1):

Use number = newnumber; instead of number = ""; in the operators click function because square root function takes the value of number. Its working for your square root function.